# Prevent automatic search in Firefox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, keypress

I would like to use JavaScript to disable Firefox's automatic search function (a search box appears on a keypress outside an input area, even without explicitly calling Ctrl+F).

I can use

```
$(window).keypress(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault()
    // other code
}
```

But this disables the default action for all keypresses, like Ctrl+T to open a new tab.

Is there a way to disable the search function selectively?

Comment: http://www.makingdifferent.com/disable-ctrl-u-ctrl-c-right-click-webpage/ this link should be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just prevent the Firefox' search box with the key presses you want to have in your webpage. All others would still open the search box - which might be even a nice feature.

E.g. if you are expecting input in the number keys 1 - 4 you could use:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  // Prevent default for keys 1, 2, 3, 4
  if (keycode === 49 || keycode === 50 || keycode === 51 || keycode === 52) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var pressedKeys = [];
$(window)
  .keydown(function(e) {
     pressedKeys.push(e.which);
     if (pressedKeys.indexOf(70) !== -1 && pressedKeys.indexOf(17) !== -1) {
       e.preventDefault();
     }
  })
  .keyup(function(e) {
    var index = pressedKeys.indexOf(e.which);
    if (index !== -1)
     pressedKeys.splice(index, 1);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! this pointed me to the right direction. But the response above solved it.